# TransactionManager already defined in Spring Batch using EclipseLink JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-batch, eclipselink

have to use `EclipseLink` as JPA implementation for my Spring Batch Job because `Hibernate` lacks an important feature that I need.

Unfortunately, after exchanging Hibernate with EclipseLink, i get the following error when starting my batch jar:

```sh
$ java -jar my-batch.jar

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-09-17 15:52:38.387 ERROR 15708 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'transactionManager', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [path/to/my/EclipseLinkJpaConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

In my current pom.xml u can see my dependencies and how i exchanged Hibernate with EclipseLink:

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.7.RELEASE>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

In addition to this I added `EclipseLinkJpaConfiguration` which is required in order to use EclipseLink in Spring:

```java
@Configuration
public class EclipseLinkJpaConfiguration extends JpaBaseConfiguration {
    protected EclipseLinkJpaConfiguration(DataSource dataSource,
                                          JpaProperties properties,
                                          ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManager) {
        super(dataSource, properties, jtaTransactionManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING, "false");
        map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.LOGGING_LEVEL, SessionLog.FINER_LABEL);

        return map;
    }
}
```

I have no idea whats causing this.
Adding `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` is obviously a temporary solution but i would like to fix this.
I'd appreciate any help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/816. The fix is planned for version 5.0, planned for Q4 2022.

In the meantime, you can allow bean definition overriding or rename your bean to something other than `transactionManager`.

Comment: Using spring-boot-starter-batch 2.7.14 and getting same error. I have tried overriding but that does not appear to work. Any other ideas on fixing this? I can't change the version.

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-batch 2.7.14` brings spring batch 4, but the fix is in spring batch 5 (brought by spring-boot-starter-batch 3.0.0+). As mentioned in the answer, for spring batch 4, you can allow bean definition overriding or rename your bean to something other than `transactionManager`.

Comment: Thanks, and what do I have to do after I update to 3.0.0+ ?

Comment: In v5.0+, Spring Batch does not unconditionally expose a transaction manager bean, it will look for one in the application context. So you have to define one manually, or if you use Spring Boot, make Spring Boot autoconfigure one.